# Hand Calculating Odd Ratios

Tags: python-2.7

I'm suck receiving the following when trying to hand calculate odd ratios:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

So far I've read the dataset:

```
df_raw = pd.read_csv("../assets/dataset/admissions.csv")
```

Created a frequency table:

```
admit = df_raw['admit']
gre = df_raw['gre']
gpa = df_raw['gpa']
prestige = df_raw['prestige']
pd.crosstab(admit, [gre, gpa, prestige], rownames=['Admit'], colnames=['GRE', 'GPA', 'Prestige'])
```

Got dummies for prestige:

```
dummy_ranks = pd.get_dummies(prestige)
```

Now after running this, I'm getting the error:

```
cols_to_keep = ['admit', 'gre', 'gpa']
handCalc = df[cols_to_keep].join(dummy_ranks.ix[:, 'prestige_1':])
print handCalc.head()
```

Any thoughts on where I could be wrong?

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the prefix when you create the dummy variables, as it is written now, when you create the dummy variables, the column names are just going to be the categories in the prestige column (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0).

But in your handcalc variable creation you're referencing a column called prestige_1 and that doesn't exist.

Update 
`dummy_ranks = pd.get_dummies(prestige)` to

```
dummy_ranks=(pd.get_dummies(df['prestige'], prefix='prestige_'))
```